# Deletar ultima linha em branco txt php

Tags: php, txt

Possuo um arquivo txt e preciso apagar a ultima linha, porém ela está em branco.

Tentei o código abaixo e ele apaga somente a linha de cima da ultima que seria a que está em branco.

Segue código:

```
$lines = file('file.txt'); 
$last = sizeof($lines) - 1 ; 
unset($lines[$last]); 


$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, implode('', $lines)); 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Já tentou usar expressão regular ?

Comment: Se remover o **\n** do ultimo elemento não resolveria?

Comment: Tentei está expressão `$string = preg_replace('/^\s*$/m', '/n', $string);`

Comment: `file_put_contents('file.txt',
                  implode('', file('file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));` verifique se resolve.

Comment: Não deu certo .

Comment: e se no lugar do `implode` fazer um `while` e tratar essa linha ? um pouco mais de processamento, mas acho que resolve.

Comment: já tentou `rtrim( join('', $lines ) )`?

Comment: Não, nunca tentei, mas não é bem um espaço é uma linha em branco vazia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso resolverá. Qualquer linha em branco será removida. Lembre-se que um espaço não é linha em branco, so for o caso, modifique os valores do array que estão com espaços.

```
<?php 
$lines = file('file.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines)); 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Deu certo, é isso mesmo.